# JBoss netty: How can I integrate a Telnet connection in a separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, websocket, akka, netty, actor

I am working on a web-application that connects a limited number  of Android devices (150) over WebSockets in a closed network environment based on jboss netty. The netty server also needs to forward commands over telnet to another system, therefore netty uses telnet as a client (apache telnet package).

I am wondering how to integrate this telnet connection into the netty websocket application. I am considering the following options:

- Encapsulate the Telnet connection and the telnet reader in two seperate threads.
- Encapsulate the Telnet connection in an akka Actor that starts a seperate reader-thread.
- Encapsulate the Telnect connection in a class that starts the reader thread.

My questions:

- Is it possible and is it a good idea to start threads from within netty?
- Is it possible and is it a good idea to use an actor that starts a thread?

Any suggestions as to how to solve the problem are highly appreciated.

Cheers

Peter

Comment: I do not understand why you need to create your own threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (start threads) but I would avoid it if possible. Better to write your own telnet client with netty and so make use of the nio nature of it. This should be straight forward.

So you can keep the threads to a minimum and so get the best through-put.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I looked into the telnet client example that comes with netty 4, it works but it is also based on threads (thread-pools)